# How to add a PayPal Buy Now button to my Facebook Event Page? I have the code but have no idea where to put it

Tags: facebook, button, paypal

How to add a PayPal Buy Now button to my Facebook Event Page?  I have the code but have no idea where to put it?

Answer (score 2):

I bet the Paypal buy now button is either javascript or HTML code.
Unfortunately Facebook does not allow you to place code snippet on an Facebook event page.

I think you have three solutions :

1) put the link to an external page that contains your Paypal button

2) use eventbrite.com to manage payments, and put the link of the eventbrite event on your FB page

3) Make it a free event ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a link as well. The easiest is an (unsecured) link as follows: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=your@paypal-email-address.here&amount=9.99&currency_code=GBP&item_name=Your+item+name

Replace your@paypal-email-address.here, amount, currency_code and item_name with your own values.

Note that the amount to be paid is plainly visible, so ensure you confirm the amount paid directly via your PayPal account before you assume something is paid.

If you want make it that little bit more secure; create what's called a 'PayPal hosted button'.

To create a hosted button, log in to your PayPal account and navigate to https://www.paypal.com/buttonfactory
In here, select the correct button type, enter the amount, item name, et cetera.
In Step 2, click "Host button with PayPal".
Press "Finish" to complete, and you'll be shown the HTML code.
Click on the "E-mail" tab, and you'll be given a shortened link to be used in email / your Facebook page.
The link will look as follows: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=XXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no API for adding custom content to a Facebook Event page